# how  to administer forms based authentication in sp2010 foundation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, forms-authentication

I have a public facing site for community to exchange information efficiently. I have different subsites within that site. I want to provide users forms based authentication to log in to the system. To initiate this process, i want to provide login request form to users, to send a request to administrator to provide user authentication. Towards Administrator side i want to populate a list of all of the users and there information that are pending and can be approved my administrator for login.

I have previously sucessfully applied Forms based authentication in wss 3.0 sites. Can anyone provide me right suggestions to accomplish this task sucessfully.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need to enable anonymous access to a list so users can submit requests.

Check out my blog on how to setup FBA using .Net membership class and SQL: http://davidlozzi.com/2011/07/15/sharepoint-2010-claims-based-authentication-using-net-sql-membership-provider/ This will walk you through setting up the DB and sites for FBA.

Comment: David, when making edits in we.config file of web app :<add connectionStringName="SQLAuthConnectionString" applicationName="CBA" description="Stores and 
retrieves roles from SQL Server" name="SQLRoleManager" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, 
System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />                                              do we add name of our sharepoint web application name in applicationame field mentioned above?

Comment: Sure thing, that's a unique identifier for the authentication provider to grab all users for your app.

Comment: I applied your steps, but when creating site collection it doesnt recognise user admin1 when setting primary site collection administrator. Any thoughts on that.

Comment: did you do the same steps and same application name for the central admin web.config file, and the web service?

Comment: Yes i applied all of the steps in 3 webconfig files

Comment: if central admin can't find it, then something isn't configured properly in its web.config. Can one of your existing sites find users?

Comment: I finally got that working, but i have one another error It says"The connection name 'AspNetSqlMembershipProvider' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty. (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\WebServices\SecurityToken\web.config line 144)

Comment: Make sure the settings are the same across all the web.config files. This sounds like the web service's web.config file doesn't have the same setting

Comment: I had problem in web.config of Webservices Security Token. Fixed that, it started working. I also applied the codeplex solution. That is a great tool. Thank You very much for your help david.

Comment: One more question David, Can we add any additional field in the membership request form. If it is possible can you show me the right way.